# Web Page From English To Urdu converter

Tags: translation, google-translate

I need to convert my website's pages from English to the Urdu language. For this I was using Google's Translation API, but Google translate API is not returning the correct translation of the pages.

What should I to use to get 99% accurate results when translating pages from English Language to Urdu Language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only few [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS) that you can specify when using Google Translate API and that can make a difference to your results: `source` and `model` parameters:

1. Source is the language of the source text. If you don't specify it then it will be detected automatically. As your source language is English then I don't think this will be causing any troubles.
2. [Model](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#specifying_a_model): As Urdu language is supported by the [Neural Machine Translation Model](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages#languages-nmt), if you don't specify the model, then `nmt` model will be used. You can try to use `base` model, however the `nmt` one is supposed to "provide improved translation for longer and more complex content".

Maybe expecting the model to get 99% accuracy is expecting it to be almost perfect.